# TextBox, set text area

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing my own `TextBox` class.

```
SmallOffice.Windows.Forms
{
    public class TextBox:System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    {
         System.Windows.Forms.Button button;

         public TextBox()
         {
               this.button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
               this.Controls.Add(this.button);
         }
    }
}
```

The problem is: How do I allocate a logical area for the text. For example TextBox's size will be set to `Size(200, 20)` and logical area for the text will be set to `Rectangle(0, 0, 130, 20)`.

Doing so there will be 2 areas in the TextBox. Left side for the text and the right side for the button.
This is necessary so that the text doesn't overlap with the button.

Please, give me a clue, a prompt or anything to help.

Comment: Don't contain the button in the textbox.  Rather, contain both the button and the textbox within a usercontrol.

Comment: Also: subclassing TextBox will not work as well as subclassing less legacy controls.

Answer (score 2):

Create User Control. Take table layout panel with 2 columns and 1 row, dock it in parent container and set it's background color to white. Set user control's border style as 3D.
Take textbox in first column and button in second column.

Your user control designer file code should like:

```
namespace ProgressBar
{
partial class Tbox
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
        this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(275, 42);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 50F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.panel2, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.button1, 1, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(275, 42);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // panel2
        // 
        this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.panel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
        this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(219, 36);
        this.panel2.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(219, 36);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(228, 3);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(44, 36);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "X";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // Tbox
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Name = "Tbox";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(275, 42);
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.panel2.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

}
}
```

You can use panels also for desire look. Set dock properties of every control for proper position and size.

To get and set text of textbox define property in user control:

```
public string textBoxText { get { return textBox1.Text; } set { textBox1.Text = value; } }
```

and in your form access it like:

```
tbox1.textBoxText = "Hello";
```

Comment: I have already tried that way and I had serious Design-time problems. In my situation I have to do it in my way.

Comment: What kind of issue are you facing?

Comment: Data binding. Initially I created MyUserControl and a TextBox, a Button in it with proper layout. I wanted the MyUserControl must be exposed to the designer as a TextBox

Comment: MyUserControl had a property public TextBox TextBox{get{return this.textBox;}}. But the designer is unable to bind datasource to myUserControl1.TextBox.Text.

Comment: Define text property instead of TextBox. See edited answer.